# How can I run a WSH script without seeing the Microsoft header?

Tags: wsh

When a .vbs script is run from the command line, it will by default show a Microsoft header:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.7
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

How can this be disabled?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I assume you mean with `cscript` since `wscript` doesn't show anything. You can use the `nologo` switch of `cscript` to stop the annoying copyright message from being displayed.

For example:

```
cscript /nologo xx.vbs
```

Answer (score 8):

Answering my own question...

You can do this with the `/nologo` option, e.g.

```
cscript /nologo myscript.vbs
```